# Convert One field in an Object Array data with angularjs and Javascript to another value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In an angularjs controller I have this code:

```
var ysshControllers = angular.module('theControllers', []);

ysshControllers.controller('CommonController',
    function($scope, $http, $route) {
        $scope.dbKey = $route.current.customInput;
        $scope.urlToDb = 'https://' + $scope.dbKey + '/.json';
        $http.get($scope.urlToDb).success(function(data) {
            var values = [];
            for (var name in data) {
                values.push(data[name]);
            }
            $scope.Items = values;
            });
            // Initially order by date and time
            $scope.orderProp = 'ac';
    }
);
```

It creates an object array with the name `Items`.  The key values are just labed `aa`, `ab`, `ac` etc.  When the user inputs data from a drop down menu, I want to save only values like: `1,2,3,4,5` and then when the data is imported back into the website, convert the values back.  Like `0` = `Bad`; `5` = `Very Good`.  So, for every record with the key name `ae` I want to convert the values from 1,2,3,4,5 to Bad, Okay, Fair, Good, Very Good.

I can figure out the program flow, what I need to know is how to reference the values using object oriented JavaScript I guess.

The data is structured like this:

```
C5_200630_Option 1

   aa:"Option 1"
   ab:"Toyota"
   ac:6499
   ad:"Truck"
   ae:"Tacoma, Silver, 1/2 ton 4wd"
   af:4
```

I ran this like of code:

```
alert(Object.keys($scope.UsedItems));
```

And it gives values of `0,1,2,3,4` etc.  So I guess the key values in `$scope.UsedItems` are just numbers.  I don't know how to access the key and value data specifically.  What is a simple way I can just display in an alert what the content of the array is?

I used this line:

```
alert(data[name].ad);
```

And that will reference the data in every record with the name `ad`.  So that gives me a way to identify a specific item in the record.

Okay, I figured out a solution:

```
            if (data[name].af === "3") {
                data[name].af = "Awesome!";
            }
```

Even though I figured out the solution to my problem, I still have almost no idea what I'm doing.  So if there is a better way, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an array like this

```
var example = ["Bad", "Not Bad", "Fine", "Good", "Very Good"];
```

and instead of checking value of data[name].af every time you can simply set it like this

```
data[name].af = example[data[name].af];
```

which gives you the result you want as you want data[name].af=3 should be fine and example[3] is what you want...